# How to loop post vue Javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, laravel-5, vue.js, async-await

I want to send some data at once, but when sending with loop it gets 500 duplicate id status, maybe when I click JavaScript sends data at once

```
assignment: function (event) {

            for (var i = 0; i < this.perPage; i++){
            this.$http.post('mass_assigment', {
                id_target: 5,
                id_cms_users: 4,
                updated_by: 5,
            })
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
            }
        alert('sukses')
        if (event){
            alert(event.target.tagName)
        }
    }
```

[image: pict]

Comment: It looks like you're posting the same data everytime.

Comment: Are you trying to use `i` as part of the `id`?

Comment: it's clearly a backend issue. When adding to database the unique primary keys are trying to be saved with duplicate values.

Comment: i new learn vue,,. id duplicate always

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not from the code, nor from the data you are sending as well (), the issue is the backend trying to record the data under the same id and hence sql is rejecting because there is a constraint to not accept duplicate data.

good practice is to avoid adding the primary key manually, hence it is better if you exclude it from your data/function if you are doing that.

In case you are trying to update an existing record or create a new one if there is no matching record .. you might be interested in laravel [FirstOrCreate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#other-creation-methods)

Comment: @Nanda you can always query them with no troubles, but you shouldn't enter them in the database manually (to avoid having duplicate keys which eliminates the main use of the primary keys) and let them automatically generate, by sql, but if you are generating your own code, always better to check the last entry primary key before entering the new entry.